# Getting count of one column after a distinct on two columns

Tags: django

Here is a simplified representation of my models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    template_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    ...
```

What I want to do is show the number of times a template has been used by users. So when I list out the templates, I want to be able to say `Used by X users`. The main draw is that I don't only want to count a user once (so if a user uses a template twice, they still count as "one use case"). All stackoverflow posts talk about doing something like this:

```
counts = Post.objects.all().values("template_id").order_by().annotate(count=Count("template_id"))
```

But that obviously double counts a user that uses the same template twice. I was able to do a distinct on `template_id` and `user` pairings like so:

```
Post.objects.all().values("template_id", "user__id").distinct()
# Printing this out, I get 2 distinct entries in the QuerySet:
# <QuerySet [{'template_id': 1, 'user__id': 1}, {'template_id': 1, 'user__id': 2}]>
```

However, when I try to get the counts of `template_id` (the code below), it seems to ignore the `distinct` and still double counts users.

```
Post.objects.all().values("template_id", "user__id").distinct().values("template_id").annotate(count=Count("template_id"))
# Printing this out I get `count` = 3, which double counts a user.
# <QuerySet [{'template_id': 1, 'count': 3}]>
```

For what it's worth, I wrote a quick test case which is what is failing.

```
user1 = baker.make("User")
user2 = baker.make("User")

# Populate posts
quest1 = baker.make("post.Post", user=user1, template_id=1)
quest2 = baker.make("post.Post", user=user1, template_id=1)  # Duplicate shouldn't count
quest3 = baker.make("post.Post", user=user2, template_id=1)
```

Comment: `values` followed by annotate does a group by, you should just use the [`count` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#count)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat So the thing here is that I have hundreds/thousands of templates in prod. is the only way to do this to actually go through each template and manually get the count of each one? is there not a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: The template looks like a separate entity why is `template_id` an integer field and not a foreign key? If you had a separate model for template and proper foreign keys etc. you could probably query from that model. You can try using the [`distinct` argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#id9) to `Count` maybe that helps?

Comment: yeah, it definitely should be another model. I created this years ago so my models aren't the best designed. I have a really large json that contains all the templates. I'll be working on converting that to a django model soon. ill give the distinct argument a shot!

Comment: distinct in the count does not work. it gives me count of 1 for each of the template ids.

Comment: You've already grouped on the `template_id` don't put it in `Count` try `Count("user_id", distinct=True)` you don't want distinct template ids you want distinct user ids.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I don't want distinct user ids, cause that will give me the total number of distinct templates each user has used.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work using Django's built in ORM by doing the following:

```
        template_ids = []  # My templates

        # Get the number of times each template_id was used.
        top_template_counts = (
            Post.objects.filter(template_id__in=template_ids)
            .values("template_id")  # groups by template ids
            .annotate(user_count=Count("user", distinct=True))  # Gets the number of users using each template
            .order_by("-user_count")
        )

        # Accessing `top_template_counts` 
        for template_id_count in top_template_counts[:10]:
            template_id = template_id_count["template_id"]
            count = template_id_count["parent_count"]
```